# create dialog in dialog visual studio

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I'm trying to create a 'form' type of input for my user, so I have a C++ dialog project in Visual Studio.  This project has a number of fields that can be filled in.  One of the fields requires further information, so I wanted to create a 'sub-dialog' for this application.  I popup the sub-dialog, but am unable to figure out how to get the information back into my 'main' application.

```
loan_info newLoan;
LoanDlg dlgAbout(&newLoan);
if (dlgAbout.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CString string;
    dlgAbout.GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT__LOAN_PRINCIPLE, string);
}
```

I get an error at the 'GetDlgItemText' - it seems that I am unable to get the element in the dialog at this point (because dlgAbout is now NULL).
Any pointers towards creating and accessing dialogs within 'Dialog' Visual Studio projects would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `GetDlgItemText` once the dialog has been closed. `GetDlgItemText` can only be used on an existing window. Once the dialog has been closed (for exemple by clicking on "OK")  the dialog window doesn't exist anymore. The subject is vast, please google "mfc modal dialog tutorial". [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=Vp81ypJAyVs) looks quite good.

Comment: In the `OnOK()` handler of the child dialog, call `GetDlgItemText()` and store the result to a member variable of the 'LoanDlg' class. Or else, if you have used the wizard and created member variables for the controls, just call `UpdateData(TRUE)` (maybe this is not needed either, if the default implementation in the base class does this already). In either case, after the child dialog is closed, its controls won't be of course available, but the dialog's C++ class will be, and so will the data (accessible through the member variable, eg `dlgAbout.szLoanPrinciple`).

Answer (score 0):

MFC is in part a C++ resource wrapper for native Windows resources. Commonly, the C++ object lifetime coincides with the lifetime of the wrapped resource. A notable exception are [CDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class)-derived classes, where instances outlive the native window resources.

In this case, you cannot access the native window hierarchy once [DoModal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#domodal) returns. That's what [GetDlgItemText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getdlgitemtext) tries to do. It probably shows a failed debug assertion dialog in a Debug build to inform you about this.

To work around this, you're going to have to persist the dialog's data long enough so that you can access to it, once the native window is destroyed. A common solution is to store the data in the dialog wrapper class as a public class member. You can then either manually update the class member(s) as the user enters data, or use MFC's built-in support to bind class members to controls. The latter is recommended. Details are available in the MSDN: [Dialog Data Exchange and Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange-and-validation).